# How to rotate 180 degrees but always in quadrant 1 on a coordinate grid

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, transformation, rotations

I am a software developer and I am tasked with displaying "boxes" on a grid. The X & Y grid are positive only. The X axis ranges from 0-100 and Y axis ranges from 0-50. On the Y axis 0-23 displays text information, and 24-50 displays the boxes. The issue is that when I am getting the coordinates  in the software they start from 0,0 however to correctly display it on the screen they would need to start from 0,24. This is easy I just add 24 to every Y coordinate, however I also need to rotate it 180 degrees so that the box on the top is now on the bottom and the box on the bottom is now on the top.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwjJ1.jpg) is a pic for reference. The one labeled "ORIGINAL" is drawn with the coordinates beginning from 0,0 while the bottom one labeled "FLIPPED" is rotated and starts from 0,24 and the boxes are rotated so the box that was in the top in the original drawing is on the bottom, and the box that was on the bottom is now on top.

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwjJ1.jpg)

I have hit a roadblock and cannot figure out the math to do this. It would be easier if I was flipping over the Y axis from positive to negative but I cannot figure out how I would flip the box over in the same axis. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Aren't you just doing $(x,y)\mapsto (x, 50 -y)$?

Comment: From your description, it sounds like someone put coordinates on things as if the $y$ coordinate is zero at the bottom of the window and increases as you go upward, whereas the interface that you need to use to interact with the display uses $y$ coordinate $0$ for the top of the window and the $y$ coordinate increases as you go downward. Is that your situation?

Comment: What I described in the last comment doesn't match your picture. So you need to be really sure that is the correct picture. Why should a box that is originally given to you with $y$ coordinates $2$ to $22$ be displayed so that its top is right on the boundary between the "text" and "boxes" panels, and its bottom is $6$ units above the bottom of the window? Do you sometimes receive boxes with corners at negative $y,$ or are you just not supposed to put anything in the strip of height $4$ at the bottom of the window?

Comment: Looks to me like you should be looking for a _reflection_ instead of a rotation.